# Magento MSI Aggregating the sources total in saleable qty

Tags: magento2

I have MSI enabled and have 2 sources - i want to be able to setup so saleable quantity is an aggrigate of both sources so if source 1 and 1qty and source 2 has 1 qty then saleable qty shows 2

but for some reason it seperates it out in saleable qty see attached.

when item sells and the qty is reduced from default source  - when default source is 0 the product in frontend says out of stock - yet in source 2 i still have 1qty